# Ms CRM Rename 'More Addresses' in Account and Contact entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Does anybody know how to rename 'More Addresses' in Account and Contact entities navigation pane?

The usual method would be to change the display options in the address/contact or account relationship, but this is read only in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way as well... go to Settings -> Customizations
go to the account entity and select "Messages" from the menu left. There you can find "more addresses". open this line and change the display name. Save + publish. Done :-)
Hope this helps.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: The "More Addresses" message is found within the **Address** (`customeraddress`) entity rather than the Account entity

Answer (score 0):

Apparently those kind of labels are hard-coded. It looks as if the only workaround is to follow the (unsupported) path of modifying the HTML in the OnLoad method. Something like

```
document.all.navAddresses.innerHTML = ...
```

You will have to dig into the details of the HTML to achieve the desired effect.

Good luck!